# I can't map my data and retrieve the good value

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I wrote a Web API with Entity Framework.
I have two tables, a user table and an address table. They have a many-to-many relationship

I'd like to be able to retrieve all my users with their addresses, and if they don't have any just have an empty list.

```
// Users
public class UserEntity
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public List<UserAdressEntity> Addresses { get; set; }
    public List<OrderEntity> Orders { get; set; }
}
   
    // Adress
    public class AdressEntity
{
    public int AdressId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public List<UserAdressEntity> Users { get; set; }

}

// UserAdress
public class UserAdressEntity
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public UserEntity User { get; set; }
    public int AdressId { get; set; }
    public AdressEntity Adress { get; set; }
}
```

Here I retrieve my data from the context:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<UserEntity>> GetAllWithAdresses()
 {
     return await _context.Users.ToListAsync();
 }
```

Here my Service:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<UserAdressesModel>> GetAllWithAdresses()
 {
     IEnumerable<UserAdressesModel> result = await _userRepository.GetAllWithAdresses().ContinueWith(u => u.Result.Select(r => r.ToUserAdresses()));
     return result;
 }
```

And finally my mapper:

```
   internal static UserAdressesModel ToUserAdresses(this UserEntity entity)
    {
        return new UserAdressesModel()
        {

            user = entity.ToUserModel(),
            Addresses = entity.Addresses != null
        ? entity.Addresses.Where(ua => ua.Adress is not null)
            .Select(ua => ua.Adress.ToAdressModel()).ToList()
        : new List<AdressModel>()

        };
    }
```

After this, I get my users but not the associated addresses.
Can someone help me?

Some searches on the web, several tries, etc.
use a Join, GroupJoin.

Comment: Why did you tag this question with the C language tag? I don't see anything related to C. Did you know that people with specific areas of expertise actually follow specific tags on Stack Overflow, so that relevant questions appear in their feed? If you abuse the tag system, you attract negative attention which generates noise and doesn't help you at all.

Comment: FYI Since EF Core v5, You can define a many-many join using a "skip navigation" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many?source=recommendations). So you don't need to manually `.Include` or manage the content of the join table.

Comment: Very interessing, thanks. I'm going to read this right now

Comment: @Jeremy Lakeman I've tested skip navigation but I still need to include an "Include" but no longer "ThenInclude". Or am I wrong? If I'm wrong, I'll go back and look for the error. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your "GetAllWithAdresses" is missing the "WithAddresses" aspect of the method. You would want:

```
return await _context.Users
   .Include(x => x.Addresses) // UserAddresses
       .ThenInclude(x => x.Address) // UserAddress.Address
   .ToListAsync();
```

However, be warned that this method is loading ***all*** users and their related address details. Chances are you want to just load a summary representation of users then display a detail with their address. In this case you will want a Get A User With Address:

```
public async Task<UserEntity> GetWithAdresses(int userId)
 {
    return await _context.Users
       .Include(x => x.Addresses) // UserAddresses
           .ThenInclude(x => x.Address) // UserAddress.Address
       .SingleAsync(x => x.UserId == userId);
 }
```

In which case you only need to pass the selected User ID, not an entire entity (which won't have the address details anyways) and the server can fetch by ID. It can be tempting to simply pass entities around but they are often not complete, and while in a disconnected state, can be stale. Fetching a single entity and any related details from the DB by PK is about as fast an operation as you can get, and ensures you are looking at current data state.

This approach is a bit of a rabbit hole. You will need to add explicit methods or parameters every time to support cases where you don't need related entities vs. times that you do need one or more related entities. This approach is also not very efficient when it comes to mapping to view models and such since this loads all of the data where the view model may only care about a subset. Various existing mapper libraries like Mapperly and Automapper support working directly with EF's `IQueryable` implementation and can build efficient queries to execute against the DB, avoiding the need entirely to eager load related data /w `Include`.

Comment: thank you very much, that's exactly what I need.
I completely forgot about the Include method, which is basic.
I'm sorry again.